# Не отображаются кириллические символы в терминале Debian у программ на Java скомпилированных в Win10

Tags: java, debian, windows-10, кириллица

Собственно установил я себе недавно Debian 9, не смотря на то что в линуксе новичек проблем особых не было. Установил себе jdk 8 от Oracle решил проверить работоспособность и получил странный результат, те файлы которые я создал и скомпелировал в линуксе отображают кирилицу в консоле без проблем.

Файлы же скомпилированные в Win10 показывают всякую ерунду. Хотя сама консоль настроена и работает верно, локаль и utf 8 итд.

И в win10 и debian создавал файлы в sublime text 3.

В чем может быть проблема?

PS: В java и debian новичек так что это может быть стандартная ошибка.

---

Извиняюсь что не получилось ответить сразу, да это скорей всего из-за кодировки. Но из-за какой именно кодировки я так и не понял.

Провел небольшой тест:
Создал три файла, все три сделал в SublimeText3 и сохранил с кодировкой UTF-8. Вот что было внутри.

```
class Test_Win10_Default {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ABCabc");
        System.out.println("АБВабв");
        System.out.println("àéèç");
    }
}
```

Первый файл скомпилировал в командной строке WIN10, второй файл был скомпилирован там-же в командной строке, но перед этим я написал команду `chcp 65001` поменяв кодировку командной строки на UTF-8. Результат такой, оба файла отображали символы корректно толь после того как я менял кодировку, при это закрывая командную строку кодировка не сохранялась и приходилось опять вводить команду на её смену.

Далее, я перешел в Debian и создал файл с точно таким же кодом, там всё работало нормально. Файлы созданные в Виндовс не работали, оба. Перейдя же обратно в Виндовс я обнаружил что третий файл созданный в Линукс не работает в Виндовс. Даже после смены кодировки терминал отображал первые две строки, а вот третью с французскими буквами, он не понимал.

В общем я запутался в конец. Неужели нет способа поставить одну кодировку Юникод в обеих системах чтобы больше не думать о таких вещах?

Comment: Важнее не в чём вы создавали файлы, а как вы их компилировали. Компилятор по умолчанию использует системную кодировку. Системная кодировка Windows - это cp1251.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию компилятор использует системную кодировку. В Windows это cp1251. Поэтому собранные под Windows классы показывают крякозяблы. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо явно указать компилятору какую кодировку использовать

```
javac -encoding utf-8 Test_Win10_Default.java
```

Впрочем, вывести символ `à` в консоль cmd вам это всё равно не поможет. Ничто не поможет нормально выводить двухбайтовую кодировку в консоль заточенную под использование однобайтовой cp866.

Comment: Но ведь выводиться, если я компилирую с дефолтными настройками Виндовс и далее пишу в консоль "chcp 65001" то все символы отображаются нормально.

Comment: `chcp` - это костыль, который рано или поздно приведёт к другим проблемам.

Comment: Спасибо, помогла команда javac -encoding utf-8 Test_Win10_Default.java

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Но нижняя строка с ней не отображается все равно (

Answer (score 2):

А кодировка файлов из винды случайно не cp1251?
Не знаю под какой кодировкой работает сейчас виндовс, но если ср1251, а в линуксе у вас используется utf-8, то думаю причина именно в этом.

Попробуйте сохранить свои файлы или сконвертировать в utf-8.

Comment: Если вы не уверены, не стоит отвечать.

Comment: Прошу прощения, такая манера рассуждения. Как правило быть на 100% уверенным о том что происходит на чужом компе, с чужими размышлениями по-вопросу невозможно :). Но, если я верно понял, то ситуация очень похожа :).

Comment: В поле для ответа ожидается аргументированный ответ, а не рассуждения или уточнения. На 100% не может быть уверен никто. Но вы же можете проверить в  вашей среде разработки и дать вполне убедительный ответ подкреплённый примерами.

Comment: и не хватает примера конвертации.

Comment: @0xdb, нормальный ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy не могу согласиться.

Comment: Ух, какая полемика разраслась вокруг элементарной задачи :). Ну раз тут форум по делу, то суть вопроса была о том "почему", а не "как". Если человеку понадобится задать вопрос "как" провести подобную операцию, то он его задаст. Дополнительные же комментарии могут привести к ещё большей запутанности в вопросе.
На тему - сделайте пример и приведите. У меня нет исходных данных с компьютера человека и то что я могу сделать у себя может кардинальным образом отличаться от имеющегося у  него.